# equivalence of definitions for connected objects?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

For an extensive category, the following conditions are equivalent for an object $C$.

- The representable copresheaf of $C$ commutes with coproducts.
- The $C=X\amalg Y\implies X\text{ or }Y$ is $0$ and $C\neq 0$

How to prove these are equivalent?

Following Zhen Lin's hint for the $\Uparrow$ direction, I tried looking at the diagram below. One of the characterizations of extensivity says the top row must now be a coproduct. By connectedness, one of the top coproduct injections must be an iso. Suppose wlog the left one is an iso (as in the diagram). Then $\mathrm{Hom}(A\times_{A\amalg B}C,A+B)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(C,A+B)$. However, I want to LHS to be $\mathrm{Hom}(A\times_{A\amalg B}C,A)$, and I'm not sure how to get there.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A\times_{A\amalg B}C @>{\cong}>> C @<<< B\times_{A\amalg B}C\\ @VVV @V{f}VV @VVV \\ A @>>> A+B @<<< B  \end{CD}$$

How to finish this direction?

Comment: Hint for the downward direction: consider $\mathrm{id} : C \to C$ and use the fact that $\mathrm{Hom}(C, X) \amalg \mathrm{Hom}(C, Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}(C, C)$ is a bijection.

Comment: @ZhenLin could you give another hint? I'm not getting anywhere so far. I don't see what the arrow $\mathrm{Hom}(C, X) \amalg \mathrm{Hom}(C, Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}(C, C)$ can be. It seems the codomain should be $\mathrm{Hom}(C, X\times Y)$...

Comment: It is the canonical comparison arrow induced by the injections $X \to C$ and $Y \to C$.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks for the hint! What about the converse?

Comment: For that you will need to use the fact that coproducts are pullback-stable in extensive categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin I added what I tried so far, could you help me wrap up?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. One of the two arrows in the top row is an isomorphism, but you don't know which one. So you have to consider both on equal grounds.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't understand. What is lost if I assume a specific one of them is an iso. How do I consider both on equal grounds"?

Comment: The situation is not as symmetric as you imagine. I can't really explain it any better than that.

Comment: @ZhenLin I believe you it isn't symmetric, but I don't understand why. Could you explain why it isn't symmetric? Or tell me how to prove the statement so that I'll try and figure it out by myself?

Comment: You have to consider _both_ cases. If the left insertion is an isomorphism, then ...; if the right insertion is an isomorphism, then ...; hence $f : C \to A \amalg B$ factors ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the proof of theorem 2 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+object#characterization_in_terms_of_coproducts). For $\Uparrow$ use the diagram below noting that coproduct injections are monos in extensive categories. The proof is spelled out in the link.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A\times_{A\amalg B}C @>>> C @<<< B\times_{A\amalg B}C\\ @VVV @V{f}VV @VVV \\ A @>>> A+B @<<< B  \end{CD}$$

The $\Downarrow$ direction is basically "$1_C$ can't have a preimage".